# Passport.js showing backend error's stack trace to user

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm currently using Passport.js with the [passport-discord](https://npmjs.com/package/passport-discord) strategy. When a user goes to the `/auth/callback` route on my server, and there's an error, it shows the stack trace. I'm trying to figure out how to rid of this due for security reasons, I do not want API credentials leaked.

Here is the endpoint's code:

```
router.get('/callback', passport.authenticate('discord', {
    failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/'
}), (req, res) => {
    return res.send('<script>if(window.opener) { window.opener.postMessage(\'redirect\'); window.close(); } else { window.location.href = \'http://localhost:3000/dashboard\'; }</script>');
});
```

Upon going to this URL, the error and stack trace is shown to the user. This happens before reaching the strategy callback function.

[image: screenshot of browser error]

Full error with stack trace:

```
TokenError: Invalid "code" in request.
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/Users/redacted/Documents/discord-oauth/api/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:373:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/Users/redacted/Documents/discord-oauth/api/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:420:16)
    at /Users/redacted/Documents/discord-oauth/api/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:177:45
    at /Users/redacted/Documents/discord-oauth/api/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (/Users/redacted/Documents/discord-oauth/api/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/redacted/Documents/discord-oauth/api/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1344:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Your request is to `/auth/discord` but you've only shown the `/callback` route handler

Comment: My bad. It does the same thing on /callback though @Phil